# CodeIgniter:função anchor

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou iniciando com o CodeIgniter, utilizo a versão 2.2 e estou tendo problemas ao utilizar a função `anchor`.

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function anchor()

Não sei se é o motivo é a versão ou algo assim, se alguém puder me ajudar ou falar outra função que possa utilizar com o mesmo resultado, agradeço.

Comment: Por acaso fez o carregamento do helper `url` no local onde esta chamando o `anchor`? No autoload ou no controller? Coloque um pouco mais detalhes.

Comment: Onde acontece esse erro no seu código? Poste um pouco de código pra gente. Veja [ask] e faça um [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Verifique o arquivo `autoload.php` na pasta `config` ou em seu `controller` e coloque a seguinte função:

```
<?php
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Oi Renato, testei tanto no autoload quanto no controller, mas não funcionou. Poderia ser algum problema de versão?